# Licença do DreamSpark - Posso usar em mais de uma máquina?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

Tenho uma licença do SQL Server 2014 Enterprise e uma do Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, ambas obtidas através do DreamSpark. Como não sabia que futuramente iria precisar deles em duas máquinas, não li os termos de uso na hora de fazer o download.

Agora gostaria de saber se posso usar as mesmas licenças tanto em meu notebook como no meu Desktop sem infringir o EULA. Tentei verificar a documentação no site do DreamSpark, mas [os termos de uso do mesmo](http://www.microsoft.com/portugal/misc/cpyright.htm) não possuem esse tipo de informação.

Gostaria então de saber se alguém poderia me apontar para uma documentação online da Microsoft (ou fonte confiável, a seu critério), referente aos termos de uso de seus softwares no programa DreamSpark a fim de que eu possa me informar se posso usar a mesma licença simultâneamente em duas máquinas pessoais.

Comment: Eu quem negativei a sua pergunta. Com todo respeito, Arthur, mas isso - na minha opinião - não é uma pergunta válida pro SO. Todos nós sabemos o caminho para a resposta da sua pergunta e você mesmo podia tomar ele.

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre assuntos voltados à EULA de um software proprietário.

Comment: Essa pergunta [está sendo debatida no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1306/215). Antes de votar para fechar (ou reabrir, caso já tenha sido fechada) dêem uma olhada lá, e expressem suas opiniões!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do [EULA](https://www.dreamspark.com/Student/Direct-EULA.aspx) pode instalar nos dois computadores dado que sejam seus e que sejam somente para fins académicos.

Pelo que entendi no continuação da pesquisa, tal como numa subscrição MSDN, o software instalado nos computadores só pode ser utilizado por si.

Comment: Fiquei com uma pequena dúvida na letra c) do item 3. O que será que eles entendem como "determinados produtos do sistema operacional Windows"? O próprio sistema operacional? Ou ferramentas como o Office e Visio?

Comment: A alinea é sobre o próprio sistema operativo. Segundo a alínea só pode instalar SOs obtidos pelo DreamSpark caso o computador de destino tenha uma licença válida.

Comment: Apesar de algumas pessoas estarem questionando a validade da minha pergunta, o fato é que a sua resposta contém um link para uma página oficial, que eu não tinha encontrado, e que contém a resposta para a minha pergunta, portanto vou aceitá-la. Obrigado.